# SafeArrayPutElement delphi

Tags: delphi

Estou com um problema um pouco grande.
Tenho uma DLL em C# com alguns props que são arrays
`string[] teste;`
e gero a TLB. Ao importar para o Delphi 2007 a TLB. O array "teste" vai como `PSafeArray`.

Como eu faço pra popular esse array através do delphi?

Eu já crio o array, determino o tamanho. Porém, ao preencher com a informação que eu quero, ele não preenche, deixa a posição no array vazia.
Alguém saber me explicar o que está faltando eu fazer?

Segue trecho do código, onde "`dados.PreencheDados`" é uma função em C# para exibir o `dados.teste[x]`:

```
Bounds[0].lLbound := 0;
Bounds[0].cElements := 1;
x := 0;
dados.teste := SafeArrayCreate(varOleStr,1,Bounds);
SafeArrayPutElement(dados.teste,x, 'Testando');
dados.PreencheDados;
```

Eu consegui fazer funcionar semana passada, porém, apaguei o treco do código que funcionava e agora deu um branco e não consigo mais. Espero que alguém me ajude.

Comment: Tem certeza que não é problema de que no delphi os arrays começam na posição 1 e no C#, na posição 0?

Comment: Os arrays em delphi eu determino a posição inicial. Quando eu coloco `Bounds[0].lLbound := 0;´ eu digo que a menor posição do array é a 0.